# best way to format multiple onclick buttons

Tags: javascript, forms, button

Back again! I always get such great responses here!

I currently have a HTML site with multiple onclick buttons calling up a js function allowing users to "opt-in" to certain notification services. If the user wants to op-in to multiple groups, they are required to hit each button one at a time.

It technically works, but as you can imagine it certainly doesn't look pretty. Additionally, the way it's set up now, the user doesn't get any feedback that they have successfully subscribed to said group (not a huge concern though).

Here's a snip of the code right now:

```html
<button onclick="_pcq.push(['addSubscriberToSegment', '50cc']);">
50cc
</button>
<button onclick="_pcq.push(['addSubscriberToSegment', '65a']);">
65A
</button>
<button onclick="_pcq.push(['addSubscriberToSegment', '65b']);">
65B
</button>
<button onclick="_pcq.push(['addSubscriberToSegment', '85a']);">
85A
</button>
<button onclick="_pcq.push(['addSubscriberToSegment', '85b']);">
85B
</button>
```

I should also note that although I only listed 5 buttons here, the website actually has more than 20...which is pretty overwhelming.

Does anyone have an elegant way (open to suggestions) to format this? 
I thought of doing bullets, but I struggled with getting the form to run 'addSubscriberToSegment' with different values off of one submit button.

Surely it's just my lack of expertise that has got me stumped. Perhaps some of you will have a nicer solution for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace with checkboxes?

Comment: The entire technique of inline events isn't good, use `EventTarget.addEventListener()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Even your existing layout could be implemented more elegantly, by making them `<button data-segment="50cc">50cc</button>` and then using a  single, delegated click handler that retrieves the value to add from the `data-` attribute. (Or if the value will always be the same as the button text you could omit the `data-` attribute too.)

Answer (score 0):

I would do nested checkboxes for something like this. Each option has a checkbox, but there are also general sections that you can check on or off to enable/disable a group of options. Take a look at [this codepen](http://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/RPZZPe) by *lonekorean* for an idea how to style them, you can add a little bit of `javascript` to make parent checkboxes enable/disable their children items.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, probably, is to replace your buttons with checkboxes, as mentioned by u_mulder.

In any case it is better to create a function where you can handle the subscription and the notification instead of pushing things on the fly into an array.

for example:

```
function subscribeAnything(codeVariable){
    _pcq.push(codeVariable);
    alert("Great you have subscribed to " + codeVariable);
}
```

Then you add an eventlistener as commented by Jordan Davis to link this function.

If you decide to effectively replace the buttons by checkboxes, you could set the subscription code into the name or id of each checkbox and then loop trough your checkboxes to push them into your array.

```js
var myChbxArray = [];
var btn = document.getElementById("pushCheckBoxes");
btn.addEventListener("click", pushAllChbxIntoArray, false);

function pushAllChbxIntoArray(){
  myChbxArray = []; // clear content of array
  
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked == true) {
           myChbxArray.push(inputs[i].name);
      }  
  }
  
  notification();
}

function notification(){
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("result");
  
  myDiv.innerHTML = "You have checked the following checkboxes:<br>";
  
  for(var i = 0; i < myChbxArray.length; i++) {
      myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + myChbxArray[i] + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="checkboxList">
  <ul>
    <li><label for="chk1"><input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1">Chk1</label></li>
    <li><label for="chk2"><input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2">Chk2</label></li>
    <li><label for="chk3"><input type="checkbox" name="chk3" id="chk3">Chk3</label></li>
    <li><label for="chk4"><input type="checkbox" name="chk4" id="chk4">Chk4</label></li>
  </ul>
  <button id="pushCheckBoxes">ClickMe</button>
</div>
<div id="result">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```